# How to catch this Python exception: error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, sockets, exception, python-2.7

I am trying to catch this particular exception (and only this exception) in Python 2.7, but I can't seem to find documentation on the exception class. Is there one?

```
[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

My code so far:

```
try:
  # Deleting filename
  self.ftp.delete(filename)
  return True
except (error_reply, error_perm, error_temp):
  return False
except # ?? What goes here for Errno 10054 ??
  reconnect()
  retry_action()
```

Comment: Most likely, whatever gets thrown, derives from the built-in ``Exception`` (if whoever wrote this followed [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html)), so you can catch it and inspect its type.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error type is socket.error, the documentation is [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html).
Try modiffying your code like this:

```
import socket
import errno  

try:
    Deleting filename
    self.ftp.delete(filename)
    return True
except (error_reply, error_perm, error_temp):
    return False
except socket.error as error:
    if error.errno == errno.WSAECONNRESET:
        reconnect()
        retry_action()
    else:
        raise
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try doing something like :

```
try:
    # Deleting filename
    self.ftp.delete(filename)
    return True
except (error_reply, error_perm, error_temp):
    return False
except Exception, e:
    print type(e)  # Should give you the exception type
    reconnect()
    retry_action()
```

Comment: Just wanted to comment: This is a good solution since it lets you separate FTP command-related errors from the other errors.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to filter exceptions, the first step is to figure out the exception type and add it to an except clause. That's normally easy because python will print it out as part of a traceback. You don't mention the type, but it looks like socket.gaierror to me, so I'm going with that.

The next step is to figure out what is interesting inside of the exception. In this case, `help(socket.gaierror)' does the trick: there is a field called errno that we can use to figure out which errors we want to filter.

Now, rearrange your code so that the exception is caught inside a retry loop.

```
import socket

retry_count = 5  # this is configured somewhere

for retries in range(retry_count):
    try:
        # Deleting filename
        self.ftp.delete(filename)
        return True
    except (error_reply, error_perm, error_temp):
        return False
    except socket.gaierror, e:
        if e.errno != 10054:
            return False
        reconnect()
return False
```