# Errno 10054 while scraping HTML with Python: how to reconnect

Tags: python, html, runtime-error, screen-scraping

I'm a novice Python programmer trying to use Python to scrape a large amount of pages from fanfiction.net and deposit a particular line of the page's HTML source into a .csv file. My program works fine, but eventually hits a snag where it stops running. My IDE told me that the program has encountered "Errno 10054: an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

I'm looking for a way to get my code to reconnect and continue every time I get the error. My code will be scraping a few hundred thousand pages every time it runs; is this maybe just too much for the site? The site doesn't appear to prevent scraping. I've done a fair amount of research on this problem already and attempted to implement a retry decorator, but the decorator doesn't seem to work. Here's the relevant section of my code:

```
def retry(ExceptionToCheck, tries=4, delay=3, backoff=2, logger=None):

    def deco_retry(f):

        @wraps(f)
        def f_retry(*args, **kwargs):
            mtries, mdelay = tries, delay
            while mtries > 1:
                try:
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
                except ExceptionToCheck as e:
                    msg = "%s, Retrying in %d seconds..." % (str(e), mdelay)
                    if logger:
                        logger.warning(msg)
                    else:
                        print(msg)
                    time.sleep(mdelay)
                    mtries -= 1
                    mdelay *= backoff
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return f_retry  # true decorator

    return deco_retry


@retry(urllib.error.URLError, tries=4, delay=3, backoff=2)
def retrieveURL(URL):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
    return response


def main():
    # first check: 5000 to 100,000 
    MAX_ID = 600000
    ID = 400001
    URL = "http://www.fanfiction.net/s/" + str(ID) + "/index.html"
    fCSV = open('buffyData400k600k.csv', 'w')
    fCSV.write("Rating, Language, Genre 1, Genre 2, Character A, Character B, Character C,     Character D, Chapters, Words, Reviews, Favorites, Follows, Updated, Published, Story ID, Story Status, Author ID, Author Name" + '\n')    

    while ID <= MAX_ID:

        URL = "http://www.fanfiction.net/s/" + str(ID) + "/index.html"
        response = retrieveURL(URL)
```

Whenever I run the .py file outside of my IDE, it eventually locks up and stops grabbing new pages after about an hour, tops. I'm also running a different version of the same file in my IDE, and that appears to have been running for almost 12 hours now, if not longer-is it possible that the file could work in my IDE but not when run independently?

Have I set my decorator up wrong? What else could I potentially do to get python to reconnect? I've also seen claims that the SQL native client being out of date could cause problems for a Window user such as myself - is this true? I've tried to update that but had no luck.

Thank you!

Comment: I assume there's more to the `while` loop at the end of the provided code than what you show, right? Otherwise you've got an infinite loop

Comment: Yup! I didn't want to post the whole thing because in the while loop the code goes on with a lot of string formatting. 

I've confirmed that the code's not stuck in any kind of infinite loop, as I have a print command that indicates when the code has retrieved a new URL and extracted its HTML.

Comment: As a side note, you might want to check out the [Python Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). I've found it easier to use than urllib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are catching URLErrors, which Errno: 10054 is not, so your `@retry` decorator is not going to retry. Try this.

```
@retry(Exception, tries=4)
def retrieveURL(URL):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
    return response
```

This should retry 4 times on any Exception. Your `@retry` decorator is defined correctly.

Comment: @Rob Watts answer will also work, but I personally lean toward a more all-encompassing reconnect. Your code runs, so in general you don't really care what the error is, you just want to try to reconnect regardless of the error.

Comment: That makes sense! I feel pretty dumb now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Don't feel dumb - the retry decorator was pretty confusing for me when I first started. Sometimes a second eye helps

Answer (score 1):

Your code for reconnecting looks good except for one part - the exception that you're trying to catch. According to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832643/how-to-catch-this-python-exception-error-errno-10054-an-existing-connection), an `Errno 10054` is a `socket.error`. All you need to do is to `import socket` and add an `except socket.error` statement in your retry handler.