# "An Existing Connection was Forcibly Closed by the Remote Host" why? And how do I fix it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication, error-handling, request

I'm trying to open a website that is protected by authentication. I decided to go with the requests module and it works great with basic websites (facebook being my prime testing site). However, when I try to use it on websites with "more advanced" authentification (ie, several firewalls as well as password protected" I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Pre-SiDashboard\more_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, auth=('user','pass'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 461, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 567, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\adapters.py", line 395, in send
    raise ProxyError(e)
ProxyError: ('Cannot connect to proxy.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))
```

This is my code (websites, proxies and password hidden):

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import getpass

proxies = {
    "http": "http://a_proxy.blah.blah.org",
    "https": "http://a_proxy.blah.blah.org",
    }

url = 'https://example.com/here/there/'

user = getpass.getuser()
password = getpass.getpass("password:")

r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, auth=('user','pass'))
#print r.text
print r.cookies

print r.status_code
```

Another question told me what the error was but I don't understand how to fix it...
Help is appreciated :)

Comment: Pray tell what the other question was.

Comment: @merlin2011 I got that it was a socket type error from a few places but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832643/how-to-catch-this-python-exception-error-errno-10054-an-existing-connection) was where I saw it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem occurs due to the authentication process, you should pass the user and password to the auth argument (assuming the credential is the user's input) :

```
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, auth=HTTPProxyAuth(user, password))
```

Comment: @Isa: what proxy server do you use?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. I'm using Basic Auth with a proxy that is created by the company I work for.